# Equivalent of "IN" that uses AND instead of OR logic?

Tags: sql-server, tags, where-clause, sql-match-all

I know I'm breaking some rules here with dynamic SQL but I still need to ask.  I've inherited a table that contains a series of tags for each ticket that I need to pull records from.

Simple example...  I have an array that contains "'Apples','Oranges','Grapes'" and I am trying to retrieve all records that contain **ALL** items contained within the array.

My SQL looks like this:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE basket IN ( " + fruitArray + " )
```

Which of course would be the equivalent of:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE basket = 'Apples' OR basket = 'Oranges' OR basket = 'Grapes'
```

I'm curious if there is a function that works the same as IN ( array ) except that it uses AND instead of OR so that I can obtain the same results as:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE basket LIKE '%Apples%' AND basket LIKE '%Oranges%' AND basket LIKE '%Grapes%'
```

I could probably just generate the entire string manually, but would like a more elegant solution if at all possible.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Short answer. No. You could build sub-queries, but I do not think that is what you were asking.

Comment: `IN` is not a function by the way. It's an operator.

Comment: What type is the `basket` column?

Comment: VARCHAR(512)  I did have it set as an indexed text but it was WAY too slow to be worthwhile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common problem in SQL.  There are basically two solutions:

1. Match all rows in your list, group by a column that has a common value on all those rows, and make sure the count of distinct values in the group is the number of elements in your array.

   ```
   SELECT basket_id FROM baskets
   WHERE basket IN ('Apples','Oranges','Grapes')
   GROUP BY basket_id
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT basket) = 3
   ```
2. Do a self-join for each distinct value in your array; only then you can compare values from multiple rows in one WHERE expression.

   ```
   SELECT b1.basket_id
   FROM baskets b1
   INNER JOIN baskets b2 USING (basket_id)
   INNER JOIN baskets b3 USING (basket_id)
   WHERE (b1.basket, b2.basket, b3.basket) = ('Apples','Oranges','Grapes')
   ```

Answer (score 0):

There may be something like that in full text search, but in general, I sincerely doubt such an operator would be very useful, outside the conjunction with `LIKE`.

Consider:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE basket ='Apples' AND basket = 'Oranges'
```

it would always match zero rows.

Answer (score 0):

If `basket` is a string, like your example suggests, then the closest you could get would be to use `LIKE '%apples%oranges%grapes%'`, which could be built easily with `'%'.implode('%', $tags).'%'`

The issue with this is if some of 'tags' might be contained in other tags, e.g. `'supercalifragilisticexpialidocious' LIKE '%super%'` will be true.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do `LIKE` comparisons, I think you're out of luck. If you are doing exact comparisons invovling matching sets in arbitrary order, you should look into the `INTERSECT` and `EXCEPT` options of the `SELECT` statement. They're a bit confusing, but can be quite powerful. (You'd have to parse your delimited strings into tabular format, but of course you're doing that anyway, aren't you?)

Answer (score 0):

Are the items you're searching for always in the same order within the basket?  If yes, a single LIKE should suffice:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE basket LIKE '%Apples%Oranges%Grapes%';
```

And concatenating your array into a string with % separators should be trivial.